# Need help in customising tab bar in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a customised tab bar with border line for tab bar (as mentioned below) in the body of flutter app and need your help in completion of the tab bar.

I am looking to achieve similar design as mentioned below:

[image]

Below is the image and code i have achieved so far:

[image]

My code so far:

```
TabBar(
                unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white,
                indicatorColor: Colors.white,
                labelColor: Colors.white,
                indicator: const BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border(
                    top: BorderSide(width: 1.0, color: Colors.white),
                    left: BorderSide(width: 1.0, color: Colors.white),
                    right: BorderSide(width: 1.0, color: Colors.white),
                    bottom:
                        BorderSide(width: 1.0, color: Colors.transparent),
                  ),
                ),
                tabs: const [
                  Tab(
                    child: Text("LOGIN"),
                  ),
                  Tab(
                    child: Text("SIGN UP"),
                  ),
                ],
                controller: _tabController,
              )
```

Unable to achieve the borders for tabs and line at bottom of tabs. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
class Lal extends StatefulWidget {
  const Lal({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Lal> createState() => _LalState();
}

class _LalState extends State<Lal> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final TabController _controller;
  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.black,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(40),
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        body: Stack(
          clipBehavior: Clip.none,
          children: [
            const SizedBox(
              height: 40,
              width: double.maxFinite,
            ),
            Positioned.fill(
              top: 47.2,
              child: Container(
                height: 2,
                color: Colors.white,
                width: double.maxFinite,
              ),
            ),
            TabBar(
              unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white,
              indicatorColor: Colors.white,
              labelColor: Colors.white,
              indicator: const BoxDecoration(
                border: Border(
                  top: BorderSide(width: 1.0, color: Colors.white),
                  left: BorderSide(width: 1.0, color: Colors.white),
                  right: BorderSide(width: 1.0, color: Colors.white),
                  bottom: BorderSide(width: 1.0, color: Colors.black),
                ),
              ),
              tabs: const [
                Tab(
                  child: Text("LOGIN"),
                ),
                Tab(
                  child: Text("SIGN UP"),
                ),
              ],
              controller: _controller,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for providing help. This is still half done. 

1. If you see the image i sent, the 2 tabs should be in the center with 60% width. Please refer to the login tab, it has left border line as well. The same way, if you click on register, it should have line after tab ends.

2. border radius for tabs as provided in the pic. If i am providing border, i am unable to provide border radius.

These 2 points are required.